# npm install takes ages in a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

Whenever I execute *npm install* within a Dockerfile, the execution of the command itself takes just as long as always, but then it takes like 15 minutes until the "Removing intermediate container" notification pops up and the build process continues. This only happens when executing *npm install*. Has anybody experienced the same and knows a way to speed that up?

Comment: Could you share the `Dockerfile` for further debugging?

Comment: Also, you could run `npm install --verbose` to have a fair idea of what the error obtained is

Comment: @MaartenDev It's happening in a number of different Dockerfiles

Comment: @TigersEye120, could this be due to the system specs? Also what OS are you on?